# How to build and visualize circuit from matrix?

Tags: ibm-q-experience, circuit-construction, qasm, quantum-computing-for-finance

In paper [Efficient quantum algorithm for solving travelling salesman problem: An IBM quantum experience](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.10928), the authors use gate $U_j$ and its decomposition
$$
U_j = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathrm{e}^{ia} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \mathrm{e}^{ib} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \mathrm{e}^{ic} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \mathrm{e}^{id} \\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & \mathrm{e}^{i(c-a)}
\end{pmatrix}
\otimes
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathrm{e}^{ia} & 0 \\
0 & \mathrm{e}^{ib}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \mathrm{e}^{i(d+c-a-b)} \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Note that they denote exponent $d+c-a-b$ by $x$ in the paper.

Then they present implementation of controlled version of $U_j$ with this circuit:

[image]

and also provide QASM code

```
cu1 ( c−a ) x , y ;
u1 ( a ) x ;
cu1 ( b−a ) x , z ;
ccx x , y , z ;
cu1 ( ( d−c+a−b ) / 2 ) x , z ;
ccx x , y , z ;
cu1 ( ( d−c+a−b ) / 2 ) x , y ;
cu1 ( ( d−c+a−b ) / 2 ) x , z ;
```

I am so confused about this. Can someone explain how the matrix, the image and the code connect to each other? It seems that each describe different circuit.

Comment: please try to make your question more focused, and ask a single question per post. You can open different posts to ask different questions. See https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Also, try to avoid screenshots of text as much as possible, as those are hardly searchable, and provide links to show where your information is from

Comment: I have just edited your question in order to be in line with requirements on formatting as mentioned by *gIS*.

Comment: @gIS: I have just edited the question to follow formatting requirements. As *Rafael* is a new user, I think a small help is necessary. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you might be interested in paper [Elementary gates for quantum computation](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9503016) explaining how complex gates can be decomposed to simpler ones. This would allow you understand how the matrix $U_j$ is decomposed.

Before we proceeed further, we have to define gate $U1$ used on IBM Q computer:
$$
U1(\lambda)=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & e^{i\lambda}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

While the authors present matrix $U_j$, the implementation of acutal gate in the figure is its controlled version. Therefore, is it a little bit different.

The controlled version of the first matrix in the decomposition correspond to the first gate in the picture. On IBM Q, it is controlled $U1$ gate with $\lambda = c-a$.

The second gate is composed of global phase gate with angle $a$ and $U1$ gate with angle $b-a$. The global phase $e^a$ is simply factored out of the matrix which leaves you with $e^a\text{diag}(1;e^{b-a})$. So controlled version of this gate is implemented with $U1$ having $\lambda = a$ applied on the control qubit and no gate (or rather identity gate $I$) applied on the target qubit. This is the controlled global phase gate. Then it is followed by controlled $U1$ with angle $b-a$.

The last matrix in the decomposition is controlled $U1$ gate described  by 4x4 matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}I & O \\ O & U1\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $I$ is identity matrix 2x2 and $O$ is zero matrix 2x2.
Since the whole $U_j$ has to be controlled, the last gate is controlled controlled $U1$ (or double controlled $U1$) implemented with last three gates in the figure. However, this part seems a little bit strange in the original paper and I think it is wrong. According to the lemma 6.1 in the paper linked above, it is possible to construct double controlled gate with CNOT gates and gates $V$ and $V^\dagger$ such that $V^2 = U$. In this case $U = U1(a)$, therefore $V = U1(a/2)$ and $V^\dagger = U1(-a/2)$. The reason is that $U1$ is a kind of a rotation, so $V^2=VV=U1(a/2)U1(a/2)=U1(a)$ and inverse to $U1(a)$ is $U1(-a)$. You can check all this by direct calculation.

Also note that exponent in the last matrix is wrong. It should be $d-c+a-b$. You can check this by calculating right side of the equation. As the matrices are presented in the paper, it is impossible to arrive back to $U_j$ on the left side.

With the decomposition provided in the question, lemma 6.1 I mentioned and correction to the exponent, the correct code for controlled version of $U_j$
should be

```
\\first matrix
u1(c-a) x,y;
\\second matrix
u1(a) x;
cu1(b-a) x,z;
\\third matrix (with lemma 6.1)
cu1((d-c+a-b)/2) y,z;
cx x,y;
cu1(-(d-c+a-b)/2) y,z;
cx x,y;
cu1((d-c+a-b)/2) x,z;
```

Finally, I would list all mistakes in the paper:

- the exponent $x$ should be $d-c+a-b$, not $d+c-a-b$
- there should not be Toffoli gates but CNOTs on qubits $x$ and $y$
- there should be sign minus before parameter of $U1$ on seventh row
- no Toffoli gate should be in the circuit diagram and $U(x)$ should be double controlled gate

You can also find some additional information about the paper in this [thread](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9507/travelling-salesman-problem-on-quantum-computer).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was so confused about this. 2 question plz:
I feel that $U(b-a)$ gate came we take out $e^{ia}$ part from the second matrix. right ?
1) When you said the last four gates in the figure- 2 Toffolis and 2 controlled $U_{1}$. Which 2 $U_{1}$. Bcoz if I see the code and figure the 2 doesn't match up. 
2) And also in the code its saying controlled $U(x)$, its different in figure ?

Comment: @Rafael: I more elaborated and edited my answer. Please note that there is a lot of mistakes in the paper you are strugling with. I rememberd my confusions when I firstly saw it. I found some my notes and tried to do my best to explain how the correct decomposition of $U_j$ should look like, I also added corrected QASM code. Hope this help. And sorry, I did also some mistakes in my first version of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and also clearing my doubt. I was so confused, I see you were also confused when you saw it. After your explanation I tried to do the matrix tensor and multiplication by hand and I got exactly the same matrix as $CU_{j}$. Now all of it make senses. Thank you for your effort to help.